# No warning in Xcode on header file including itself

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, objective-c-category

I included in my iOS project a widely used `UIImage` category to handle PDF, and got some compilation errors. This raised several questions.

Q1: Why would Xcode (or actually the LLVM compiler) not give any warning on a header file that is including itself ? I don't know if this has a special meaning in C or Objective-C that would prevent it from being seen as a typo ? In my example, I believe that a mistake was made and Foundation.h was probably the intended include:

In the category file `NSString+MD5.h` I found:

```
#import "NSString+MD5.h"

@interface NSString(MD5)
- (NSString *)MD5; 
@end
```

The corresponding `.m` does not include the `.h`. (Link is "[Here](https://github.com/mindbrix/UIImage-PDF/blob/master/UIImage+PDF/NSString+MD5.m)")

Q2: I got the compilation error because I started from an Apple project that doesn't NOT include the Foundation framework (AVCam 3.1 for iOS) ! So `NSString` was undefined. I'm a bit puzzled by this but linking with the foundation framework in xcode is like including all its headers ? I would expect again some warning at least ?

Thanks for any explanation on this probably very basic C topic.

Comment: Q2: have you checked Prefix.pch?

Comment: check the  pch file , foundation & uikit are imported there for every template project.

Comment: @bigblackdot and pawan, indeed the Prefix.pch has foundation and UIKit on most projects (not AVCam), that explains it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, in Objective-C, we `#import`, which is different from `#include`.  While `#include` will attempt to include any file you list, `#import` will never double import any file.  I imagine that this explains why there's no problem with a `.h` file trying to `#import` itself.  It's not correct for the file to import itself, but because it's an `#import`, it won't actually cause any issues.

---

As for the `.m` file not importing it's `.h`, in this case, it doesn't actually have to.  It's a good idea, out of habit, to always import the `.h` file, and any files generated by Xcode will do this automatically, however it's not always necessary.  It's only necessary when the `.h` file has declared something that the `.m` has to know about.  For example, a `@property` that you intend to use.  You've declared it in the `.h` so it'd have public access, but if you intend to use it in the `.m`, the `.m` has to know the `@property` has been defined.  Additionally, if you've `#import`ed some files in the `.h` that the `.m` needs and you don't want to import them again in the `.m`, you'd need to import the `.h` (although it's generally going to be better to just import them in the `.m`.

Here, the `.h` simply defines the exists of a method that returns an `NSString *` and is called `md5` and takes no arguments.  This means that anything importing this `.h` file can call this method and Xcode won't complain about the `md5` method not existing.  The corresponding `.m` file implements a method that coincidentally matches the one the `.h` defined.  If you deleted the `.m` file, your program would almost certainly still compile just fine... but you'd hit an unrecognized selector exception when you go to the point that `md5` was being called--despite Xcode not complaining about it.  With the `.m` in the project, this exception isn't hit.  The program figures out at run time which method to execute.

---

And finally, as for not including `Foundation.h`, every iOS project created by Xcode has `#import Foundation.h` and `#import UIKit.h` in the precompiled header file.  Any other file in your project with these imports is just redundantly importing the file, as it's already been imported by the `.pch`, but because of the magic of `#import` (vs `#include`) it's not actually double imported.

If you're working with an iOS project that doesn't have these imports in your `.pch`, your best bet is to just stick them in the `.pch`.

If you're opposed to this for some reason, the best way to fix this `md5` file is with this simple line:

```
@import Foundation.NSString;
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation on import / include! And the .pch too.